# Jquery with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to get the dropdown box value based on the previous dropdown box value in my code I need to get the first name and based on that I need to get last name in another drop down box please find my code.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var List;
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: "http://some ip address/igasp-admin/api.php/um_users?&transform=1",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {
            var i;
        List = data.um_users
            $('#userData').empty();
        for (i in List ) {
                $('#userData').append('<option value="'+ List[i].last_name + '">' + List[i].first_name + '</option>');
                $('#userorgData').append('<option value="">'+ List[i].last_name + '</option>');
            }
        }
    });


});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select  style="width: 250px;" id="userData">
 </select>
<select  style="width: 250px;" id="userorgData">
</select> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: And what is the problem? Console log errors? - assuming the Ajax works, post an example of the data too. And why async false?

Comment: I am getting data as first name in first dropdown and last name in second dropdown but when i click firstname from a dropdown then in my second dropdown lastname should be selected based upon the first value of dropdown

Comment: Why? What if there are two with the same first name?

Comment: Its my requirement that when i select first drop value as a first name then the related last name of that selected first name should be displayed

Answer (score 0):

You mean

```
$('#userData').append('<option value="'+ List[i].last_name + '">' + List[i].first_name + '</option>');
$('#userorgData').append('<option value="'+ List[i].last_name + '">' + List[i].last_name + '</option>');
```

and then have

```
$('#userData').on("change",function() {
   $('#userorgData').val(this.value); // both have the same lastname as value
});
```

As in

```js
$(function() {
  $('#userData').on("change", function() {
    $('#userorgData').val(this.value); // both have the same lastname as value
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="userData">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Lennon">John</option>
  <option value="McCartney">Paul</option>
  <option value="Harrison">George</option>
  <option value="Star">Ringo</option>
</select>
<select id="userorgData">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option value="Lennon">Lennon</option>
  <option value="McCartney">McCartney</option>
  <option value="Harrison">Harrison</option>
  <option value="Star">Star</option>
</select>
```

Comment: could you please elaborate a bit:)

Comment: Give the selects the same value (here last name). then when you change the first drop down, the second will follow. I fail to understand the value of this functionality - instead have one drop down with the surname, firstname

Answer (score 0):

If you want to automatically select a lastname based on the selection of the name you should run a second ajax on the "onchange" of the first select.

My aproach would be to listen to the "onchange" of the first select, then fire an ajax request sending the value of the select (hopefully is the id of the table) and on php side use that id to get the lastname then iterate the options of the second select and find the matching "value" when found, set that option "selected"